# Count of a count with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, rails-activerecord

Using `Usage.group(:song_id)`, I can get all the usages of any particular song in my app. Using `Usage.group(:song_id).count`, I can get a hash like `{song_id => usage_count ...}`.

How do I produce a count of that count though? i.e something like this:

```
[
  used_once: number_of_songs_used_once,
  used_twice: number_of_songs_used_twice,
  used_thrice: number_of_songs_used_thrice,
  etc.
]
```

(Okay, so really I would expect output to look something like `{1=>14, 2=>6, 3=>2, 4=>1}`).

Comment: why downvote?.. Please, write comments if you do downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inject on the hash.

```
song_values = Usage.group(:song_id).count.values

times_used = song_values.inject({}) do |used, count|
  if used[count].nil?
    used[count] = 1
  else
    used[count] += 1
  end
  used
end
```

You could use a ternary operator if you want the if/else to be one line

```
used[count].nil? ? used[count] = 1 : used[count] += 1
```

This is just looping over the songs usage count building a hash where the key is the number of times that song was used, updating the value for each count (not explained that particularly well but I hope you understand).

Comment: Thanks, I thought of using the hash but I was wondering whether there was a SQL/ActiveRecord way of doing this.